# How to specify a particular excel session or xlwings App instance among many apps?

Tags: python, excel, xlwings

I have a couple of excel sessions open. How can I specify a particular excel session to open a workbook. I can try `xw.apps[-1].books.open(filename)` to specify one and do some work on the workbook. However, when I rerun the code, a copy of the same workbook will be open in another excel session.

If I have two sessions of excel right now and I run the following code:

```
import xlwings as xw

xw.apps
```

I got the following:

```
Apps([<Excel App 11260>, <Excel App 3904>])
```

How can I pick say App 11260 specifically?

Answer (score 0):

Since v0.13, you can use the proccess id (PID) as your keys:

```
>>> import xlwings as xw
>>> xw.apps.keys()
[11260, 3904]
>>> xw.apps[11260]
<Excel App 11260>
```

Comment: Thanks Felix. my xlwings version is 14.0, which can be seen by xw.App().version. However, xw.apps.keys() gives me an error: like the following--AttributeError: 'Apps' object has no attribute 'keys'

Comment: this actually works for me: 
xl_pid=xw.apps[-1].pid
a=next(xl for xl in xw.apps if xl.pid==xl_pid)
now a is the app specified by xl_pid.